# A container with O(1) insertion (amortized) and O(n) iteration

Tags: c++, algorithm, containers

I'm looking for a set-like container class that has these basic properties:

1. has amortized O(1) insertion time, duplicate inserts are ignored
2. has O(n) iteration time *(specifically O(capacity) is not acceptable)*
3. reuses memory / only allocates when it exceeds current capacity

The use-case is that I have a larger container of objects. During each *loop* I'll add a subset of those objects to this new container. This subset can be from 1-5 objects or up to 10% of the entire set. I then iterate of the objects in this new set. Each *loop* the object will be cleared and the processed started again.

My original approach used a invasive boolean on the objects indicating if it belonged to this new set. Thus insertion was true constant time, and it used no new memory. However iteration was sub-optimal.

I've tried a `boost::unordered_set` and get worse performance than my original approach. Presumably since, as hash map, it fails to meet Point #2.

Point #3 is relevant since I'm coding at a latency level where the cost of memory allocation is very significant. Thus it is extremely unlikely that a container with continuous allocation will perform well.

Comment: I don't think O(1) insertion and duplicate detection are both possible at once.

Comment: @aschepler, pretty much all hash maps achieve that (amortized at least).

Comment: You could just use a generic hash set and use specialized memory management, either for the whole program or for the specific hash set.  This is not an easy thing to do, but if your memory allocation costs are abnormally high, the standard memory allocation algorithm may not be appropriate.

Comment: O( capacity ) is usually O( n ) no?  Unless you're using some sort of crazy data structure..

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: do you have a good hash function on those elements ? Specifically I am thinking about OpenAddressing to implement hash tables, but to meet the `O(1)` insertion you need to bound the number of tries to find a slot.

Comment: @Timmy: no, `vector` or `deque` will reserve memory in chunks, so the capacity is usually a bit larger. In exchange, you don't need to allocate memory at each insertion, so you're faster.

Comment: @MatthieuM., I don't really have a good hash, but a normal mod might be okay (they are essentially counters starting at a series of fixed intervals).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your first approach to detect whether the element is already in the set (hash map). And put it also in a list for iterating..

Comment: note that you will also have to directly connect from each element in the set to the element in the list to allow removal of elements [if it is a requirement].

Comment: @amit, strangely enough, the removal of an element has no cost restriction.  Usually `clear` will just be called, which is of course expected to be constant time.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: If no deletions are expected, then I think this approach should do. If deletions are needed, you should reference between elements in the 2 data structures.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: `clear` is NOT constant time, it calls the destructor of each object! Furthermore, with a `list`, you need to free each node of the list individually, and even if you use a `deque` you will still have this issue (though not as much).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: does this even matter? maybe he has built his own mem manager where he can throw away all his memory in no time...

Comment: @MatthieuM., I should mention my objects are fundamental data types (a pointer in this case) so there is no destructor cost.

Comment: @duedl0r: it does matter, whatever the memory management, the implementation of `vector` will call the destructors. It is a quality of implementation whether or not this is optimized out in the no-destructor case (note that C++11 provides the a trait to detect this). Anyway, if you use a `deque`, you still have to `delete` the chunks you had grabbed and no longer use on a `clear`, which is `O(N)`. As far as I know, `vector` is the only STL container which may have a `O(1)` `clear`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a linked hash set. [LinkedHashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) in java. I don't know if there exist a library in c++ that implements it, but the idea is simple: have a [hash set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) of entrees, and let the entrees also form a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Iteration is on the linked list, and insertions are made from the hash set. Note that this approach allows insertions to the list only on its back.

Comment: Yes, that is kind of the idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree). It could fit your purposes:

1. Insertion O(log(log(n))),
2. Iteration O(log(log(n))),
3. Memory... Well, just read the link provided...

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it more. It may not work since my key sizes are relative large (64-bits) compared to the number of elements (a few hundred at most).

Answer (score -1):

You can improve your method by adding a linked list.

There will be a linked list of the pointers (or whatever identifier suitable) to the inserted objects. In addition leave the boolean variable inside each your object, to know if it's already inserted to the list.

Comment: actually, not exactly, `list` is generic while linked list precises an implementation. Given the tight memory constraints (point 3), a linked list does not seem appropriate, unless you consider that the capacity is always stricly equal to the size...

Comment: I didn't understand a word from what you said. I didn't mean one should use an `std::list` if this is the point. Nevermind...